# Unexpected end of JSON input error when creating new project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Each time I use `angular/cli` to create a new project by launching the following command

```
ng new Project-Name
```

I get the following error

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...-4","@angular/common"'

I tried to force clean the cache and re-try but still face the same problem.

```
NodeJS version: 12.16.3
npm version: 6.14.4
Angular CLI version: 9.1.4
OS: Windows 10 Home win32 x64
```

**Edit:** All the commands above I run them in Powershell as administrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer but it looks like your global packages are corrupted in some way.

This bug may be caused by many different things. I suggest doing the following.

1. Install Node Version Manager (or NVM for Windows) and install Node version `10.16.1`. This is enough for angular 9 and from my experience it is the most stable version for development. This should also change your NPM version so that may also help.
2. Uninstall global angular package `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
3. Force clear cache `npm cache clean --force`
4. Just to double check `npm cache verify`
5. You can also try clearing your %temp% and %roaming% AppData/npm-cache
6. install latest angular package `npm install -g @angular/cli@<your-version>`
7. if this error still occurs, consider using another shell

If this don't solve the problem try to manually locate the package.json file that is throwing an error and investigate.